# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

while running the app I am getting the below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\flutter apps\flutter apps\dogs_breed_getx\android\app\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_eyvedltoajcnysuiedlp15vqd.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_eyvedltoajcnysuiedlp15vqd$_run_closure2) values: [build_eyvedltoajcnysuiedlp15vqd$_run_closure2@6084aaaa]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

These are the dependencies that I am using

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.1
  camera: ^0.9.4+5
  tflite: ^1.1.2
```

Anyone can help me. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app?

Comment: There is no `build.gradle` ...therefore it is rather unclear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Gradle version and also the Gradle wrapper version.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' //4+
```